# What JavaScript design pattern / common practice to use to organize multiple functions with page specific calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, design-patterns, optimization

I have a js file looking like this:

```
$(document).ready() {
    // Mostly DOM manipulation operations
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
    functionThree();
    ...
}
```

What I want to achieve is to encapsulate and organize all functions in one object, and create logic so they get called only on specific pages. I started writing something like this:

```
(function( window, document, $, undefined) {
    var MyNamespace = {};

    // Cache these to local scope
    MyNamespace.$window = $(window);
    MyNamespace.$document = $(document);

    // Functions
    MyNamespace.functionOne = function() {
        ...
    };

    MyNamespace.functionTwo = function() {
        ...
    };
})( window, window.document, window.jQuery );
```

I wonder if I am going in the right direction, and if there are any better ways of doing this with the page specific logic that I have not started implementing yet (I have a page identifier already available). I have looked at [this book written by Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) and only thing that looked similar to what I want to achieve was the Command pattern, but I am still not convinced if it would be the right choice.

Comment: I'd say AMD is the best option for sharing scripts. http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modularjavascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is kind of a class in the normal OOP sense. I personally use the following schema:

```
var OPTIONS = {
    selectorA: '.js-xxx'
};

var MyClass = function(el) {
    this.el = el;
    this._init() // private function called
};

MyClass.prototype._init = function () {
    // Do some stuff
};

MyClass.prototype.publicFunction = function() {
    // Do exposable stuff here
}

window.instance = new MyClass(document.querySelect('#myElement'));
```

In order to load these modules you should need requireJS or another AMD loader.